# Drag the canvas in interface builder

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

Is there any way to drag the canvas in interface builder, like the hand tool in Adobe Reader?

Comment: this drives me crazy too!!! where's my 'hold spacebar' and drag like every other app?!

Comment: using swift 2 and still not able to use spacebar+mouse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no hand tool like in Adobe Reader.  You can use two-finger scrolling if you have a trackpad.  You can use your mouse wheel to scroll vertically if you have a mouse wheel.  Otherwise, you just have to use the scroll bars.

Comment: that's so lame. Why couldn't they add this: space bar modifier key and drag around like photoshop...

Answer (score 2):

I think two-finger scrolling on a trackpad is the best of the suggestions here. If you're not using a trackpad, 'Zoom to Fit' may work for you. In addition to zooming, it also centres the storyboard in the window, which, nine times out of ten, is what I really want to do when I'm wishing I had a hand tool.

There's no default shortcut for it, so short of defining your own, just right- or control-click on the canvas and select 'Zoom to Fit' from the contextual menu. Alternatively, click a scene or view in the document outline to centre on that view. If the view can't fit within the visible workspace, it will automatically be scaled down to fit.

Comment: Yeah this is the best answer...I suggest using Option+Z as I just have and it works really smooth. Not only does it center and display all controllers, but also Option+MouseWheel then zooms as you like. Then just select view controller header and Option+Z...will fit just that one.  Or Command+Click and select more than one...then repeat Option+Z.  Zooms the selected.  Click outside any controller on the canvas and again Option+Z, will recenter and Zoom to Fit ALL.  Just right click and select "Zoom to Fit" if you don't key-bind with Option+Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll using keyboard:

⌘ → Scroll right

⌘ ← Scroll left

⌘ ↓ Scroll down

⌘ ↑ Scroll up

it is very painful, but what can I say, Nice Job Apple! :(

Answer (score 0):

I use keyboard shortcuts to zoom the canvas to 50% or 25% first, then use the cmd-arrow keys. That way, every arrow key has a larger effect.

Zooming to 25% makes the canvas items really small, so you can cover a lot of ground with a few cmd-arrow keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as the hand tool - and certainly not as easy as using a Magic Trackpad - but you can scroll horizontally by holding down the shift key when you use the mouse wheel.

Mousewheel:  **↑ ↓**
Shift+Mousewheel: **← →**